# SSRS project does not compile since migration - error BC30451

Tags: reporting-services, migration

Since I have migrated my SSRS project to 2017, I'm getting over 300 errors like this one: *"[rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The Color expression for the chart 'Chart18' contains an error: [BC30451] 'Helper' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."*

Helper is our custom C# project including all our custom functions and properties used by the reports. I found a post that explained that I must put a copy of the dll into the folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ depending on the VS version. But, I still get the same error.

I also checked the namespace but, in fact, nothing changed since years.

Any idea?

Regards,

Pascal

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/custom-assemblies/deploying-a-custom-assembly?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's what I tried but, it forced me to double check which folder it was... I pasted it into the wrong folder. Damn!!
The good folder is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Thanks!